# Excel to Access Import via DataGridView not Displaying all Dates

Tags: excel, vb.net, date, datagridview, import

I've written an Excel to Access import procedure in my application. The Excel spreadsheets that I'm using to import are all files that I created using the export procedure I've also written.

When viewing the data in a `DataGridView`, there is one column, which is showing dates, that is showing `NULL` values on 3 of the rows. The dates for those 3 rows are the same - 15/02/2017.

I thought at first it was because the dates were `NULL` in the spreadsheet, but they weren't.

After some investigating in Excel itself, I noticed that all of the other dates in the column were all set to 'Date' type, but these 3 cells with the problematic date were set to 'General'.

However, in my export program, I'm using this code to set the cells in this column to be dates, in dd/MM/yyyy format.

```
Dim formatRange As Excel.Range

formatRange = xlWorksheet.Range("C1", "C9999")
formatRange.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

formatRange = xlWorksheet.Range("D1", "D9999")
formatRange.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Then, just as an experiment, I changed the type of the problematic cells to 'Date' and tried the import again - But it still shows `NULL` cells.

So, I suppose  I have 2 questions, really;

- Why is the export not setting these cells to dd/MM/yyyy dates in the first place? Is it to do with the values?
- Then, why are the showing as `NULL` even after changing the type to 'Date' in Excel?

Is this a common problem, or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Formatting the Excel cells to a `Date` type is fairly meaningless as you can still type whatever you want. Since there is no code to go by, I would take a closer look at the possibility of a bad date in excel. dd/MM/yyyy can get mixed up with mm/dd/yyyy. Just guessing.

Comment: @JohnG I did consider whether or not it could be getting it confused with MM/dd/yyyy, however the column next to it is displaying 14/03/2017 perfectly fine, so that kind of debunked that theory

Comment: Have you considered taking the formatting completely off? This should display the string, if its null then it most likely has nothing to do with the dates.

Comment: The fact that you are getting null values leads me to believe you are treating the Excel file as Jet database and running a query against it.  Is this correct?  Ideally, dates should be treated as a numeric.  But often user input is taken as string value by Excel when the entered date format does not match the format expected by Excel;  the format expected Excel has nothing to do with the format applied to the Range.  This is why people often retrieve all Excel data as strings and then apply validation/type conversion before further processing.

Comment: @JohnG, okay, even when the type is set to 'General' in Excel, the `DataGridVew` is still not displaying them. Can you think of anything else that it could be?

Comment: @TnTinMn I'm using a `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` connection string for it (`Extended Properties=Excel 12.0`), then using `da = New OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", myTable), eCon)` to get the relevant data

Comment: If its a general type cell and it is not displaying, then its not a date type issue.

Comment: @David, try this extended properties part: `"Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;';"`.  This should cause a mixed data type column to read a String.  Doing it this way will require you to perform some defensive data validation (always a good idea when dealing with user input) and other manipulations before passing data to Access, but it also gives you more control.  I.E. check the DataType property of the date column to see if it is DateTime or String.  If it is String, then you know there is an issue.

Comment: @TnTinMn Connection string: `eCon = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & excel & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;';")` gives me an error message of "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 152."

Comment: David, you missed the single quote before `Excel 12`.

Comment: @TnTinMn Ah, yeah, thank you, this has solved the issue now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as @TnTinMn pointed out.

Setting the `Extended Properties` to `Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;';` displayed the problem dates, which for some reason were showing as strings. Not clear why, as the formatting was the same as the others, but the mismatched data types issue was worked around using this small change.